# color scatter plot based on labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a numpy vector of shape `(2000, 2)`, and for each element (x,y) of each row I have an associated label in a numpy vector of shape `(2000, 1)`. The labels are just an integer that can be either of the following `1,2,3,4,5,6`

how can I have a scatter plot where the color of each point is different based on its label ?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the integer labels through directly into the color argument of the scatter function

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter( data[:,0], data[:,1], c=labels )
plt.show()
```